# How to solve this one about NumPy

Tags: numpy

Could anyone explain this one to me please?

```
np.array([True, 1, 2]) + np.array([3, 4, False])
```

How come the result is:

```
array([4, 5, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

`True` is converted to 1, `False` is converted to 0.